# Why optionsMenu does not show up in fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, android-optionsmenu

I have an app with an `Activity` and multiple `Fragment`s. I want all fragments to have one default `Toolbar` which is managed by `NavigationUI`, and show a `Menu` only for the first `Fragment`. Problem: the `OptionsMenu` doesn't show up.

- This is how I setup my `Toolbar` in `MainActivity.kt`:

```kotlin
// setup Toolbar
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
binding.mainToolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
```

- `Toolbar` in `main_activity.xml`:

```xml
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

- In the `Fragment` that I want an optionsMenu:

```kotlin
 setHasOptionsMenu(true)
```

```kotlin
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.overflow_menu, menu)
}
```

I tried doing it with two `Toolbar`s, but it doesn't seem a good practice.

**How can I achieve this effect with one toolbar?**

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with `inflateMenu`:

```kotlin
val toolbar = activity?.findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.main_toolbar)
toolbar?.inflateMenu(R.menu.overflow_menu)
```

And clear it after navigation:

```kotlin
binding.navBtn.setOnClickListener {
    navController.navigate(R.id.action_startFragment_to_secondFragment)
    toolbar.menu.clear()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).